# Check if an entry already exists in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Okay, I know this question sounds really stupid in the title, but hear me out.

I'm making an API in ASP.NET using the Entity Framework. Problem is, it doesn't support automatically generating UUID's as Id's and creating automatic `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` columns.
I followed this tutorial: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/set-created-and-modified-date-in-efcore.aspx

To overcome this issue, I made a base class, called `BaseEntity`, which I use in all my models. It looks like this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

All my models just simply implement it like this example: `public class User : BaseEntity {}`.

Now I've overridden the `SaveChanges()` method over the Entity Framework to allow my own code to be processed, to automatically fill in the `CreatedAt` and update the `UpdatedAt` columns. Now I also want to automatically generate a UUID, but as you all know, they are not always 100% unique. Since this will be a large scale project, I really need to check on this, even though the chances are very small.

My overridden `SaveChanges()` method looks as follows:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    // Get the entries wether they were modified. This happens, so anything that wasn't changed, won't be updated in 'UpdatedAt'
    var entries = ChangeTracker
        .Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && (
            e.State == EntityState.Added
            || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

    // Foreach over all database entries
    foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
    {
        // UpdatedAt should always be updated, no matter what (if there is a change)
        ((BaseEntity) entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        // If the entry is new, also insert 'Id' and 'CreatedAt'
        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((BaseEntity) entityEntry.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

            ((BaseEntity) entityEntry.Entity).Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            // TODO: Here I want to automatically generate a UUID for a new model. But how?
        }
    }

    // Now return to the base method
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now my question is, how do I check if a UUID already is in the database and generate a different one if needed? There is a `TODO` comment on the location where this needs to be done. I already have a little preview of the code that has to generate the UUID above the comment.

Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to decorate your ID like so:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
```

And then you don’t need to worry about it being unique. Db will take care of it on insert. I think it uses newsequential Id command in sql rather than newid when you do that.

You can confirm that after running th new migration go to sql and check the default value of the id column, if it’s newid make sure to change it to newsequentialid and you ll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but does this have support for UUID's? And I still need to leave the line in the `SaveChanges()` method about creating a UUID right?

Comment: No you don’t need to override it. Just before you call the Add on the dbcontext set the created by, etc fields OR You can even set the default values of created by,etc. in your base entity OR best would be set that also as [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]. That will take the date time of insertion

Comment: Did it work? Don’t forget to mark it as the answer please 

Comment: I'm sorry, it's weekend and there are national holidays monday and tuesday. I won't forget to mark it once I've tried ;) I will see if there is some time today, but be patient. Know that I am grateful no matter what :p